# Announcements Webpart Customization

Tags: 2010, web-part

Can I change the default look of announcements to view them using prev and next buttons. Can this be achieved out of box, or do I need to create a custom webpart. Also how can I set the expiration date for the Announcements. I used discussion board webpart from SharePoint 2010.

Comment: When you write that you "used discussion board webpart from SharePoint 2010," does that mean instead of the announcements web part?

Comment: I think that is the first mistake I have done :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if you would get something readily available but I have implemented such requirement and can help you go in right direction.

At high level:

1. Use a custom announcement list (with custom Announcement) or use existing announcement list to store the announcements in a list.
2. Configure a Content Query Web Part to display the announcements. Here you can configure how many announcements to be displayed, filter out expired announcements, implement custom styles to display your announcement, target announcements to specific audience etc. (leverage CQWP as much as you can)
3. Once you are done, you will have announcements displayed as:

   ```
   <div id=".." style="..">
    <!-- Announcement 1 content driven by your CQWP item style -->
   <div>
   <div id=".." style="..">
    <!-- Announcement 1 content driven by your CQWP item style -->
   <div>
   <div id=".." style="..">
    <!-- Announcement 1 content driven by your CQWP item style -->
   <div>
   ```
4. Wrap the entire CQWP inside a container like:

> ```
> <div id="announcementContainer">
> <!-- Announcement items rendered using CQWP -->
> </div>
> ```

1. Now use a Jquery Cycle Plugin to rotate the announcement. Using this plug-in is extremly easy (could be as little as one line as shown below). You can also have "Prev", "Next" instead of automatic timer based rotation. Plugin and examples are available here: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/download.html

> ```
> <script>
>     $(function () {
>         $('#announcementContainer').cycle();
>     });
> </script>
> ```

Note that plugin simply hides all children (one div element for one announcement) and rotates them one by one.

Finally, you can wrap the whole functionality inside a Web Part using WebPart development skills (not covered here).

Comment: Ashish Thank you very much for this detail explanation, Let me try with this and will let you know my progress !!

Comment: Upto Step 2 I got, however from where I need to make changes to Step 3 as said in Step 4

Comment: You need to put cqwp inside a div so that the div has as many children as your announcements. And you use id of that div to cycle children under it using jquery. As u see I used id of that div in jquery function

Comment: I got that Ashish, the problem is how or where I will write that code - "    <div id="announcementContainer">
    <!-- Announcement items rendered using CQWP -->
    </div>

" from share point site!!

Comment: Actually, there are many ways to do it. For example, if you have a Page Layout, you can put it directly on the page layout. You could also provision a ASP.NET page using MODULE element and have the custom control/webpart put on that. What's your situation?

Comment: Hi Ashish, I used the default SharePoint Page with one column layout, I added CQWP by inserting the web part and configured to take the data from the Announcement, Now how to add that <div> tag for that web part.

Comment: You cannot add a div that way. You have to edit that page layout using sharepoint designer or create your own page layout.

Comment: Ok now I have open that page , say home.aspx in sharepoint designer, however I did not able to find "<div id=".." style="..">  <!-- Announcement 1 content driven by your CQWP item style --> <div> "

Comment: Please contact me in reenuiss@gmail.com, Sorry to disturb you with these questions !!

Comment: Jithu.. I wish I could help you but I am on vacation with email access only. Back to work on 4th Jan

Comment: Dnt worry, Ashish, actually this is my bros account, currently I am using it, If you could or have some time, plz contact me on above mail!!